# Mockito "unwraps" spied object when using an anonymous nested interface implementation

Tags: java, mockito

While working with some legacy tests, I recently discovered some unexpected behavior of Mockito and its spies. Consider the following class (especially note the anonymous nested implementation of `SomeInterface`)

```
public class ClassUnderTest {

  private String name = "initial value";

  private final SomeInterface impl = new SomeInterface() {
    @Override
    public void foo(String name) {
      // the following call "unwraps" the spied object and directly calls internalFoo on the "raw" object but NOT on
      // the spy (method is called on the "toBeSpied" object from testObjInstantiation and not on the "spy" instance)
      internalFoo(name);
    }
  };

  private final class SomeClass {

    private void foo(String name) {
      // works as expected when using a nested class (called on the spy)
      internalFoo(name);
    }
  }

  public void foo(String name) {
    impl.foo(name);
  }

  public void bar(String name) {
    internalFoo(name);
  }

  public void baz(String name) {
    new SomeClass().foo(name);
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  private void internalFoo(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  private interface SomeInterface {

    void foo(String name);
  }
}
```

Furthermore consider the following test:

```
@Test
void testObjInstantiation() {
  final var toBeSpied = new ClassUnderTest();
  final var spy = Mockito.spy(toBeSpied);
  spy.bar("name set on spy via bar");
  Assertions.assertEquals("name set on spy via bar", spy.getName());
  spy.baz("name set on spy via baz");
  Assertions.assertEquals("name set on spy via baz", spy.getName());
  spy.foo("name set on spy via foo");
  Assertions.assertEquals("name set on spy via foo", spy.getName()); // this fails Expected: name set on spy via foo Actual: name set on spy via baz
}
```

I would expect all assertions to succeed. However, the last one fails. The reason for this is that `spy.foo` uses the "indirection" via the `SomeInterface` implementation (`impl` member). At this point the spied object is "unwrapped". `internalFoo` which is called from `impl` is **not** called on the spy anymore but on the "raw" object. Basically it is called on the `toBeSpied` instance from the test case and **not** on the `spy` instance.
When using a nested class, everything works as expected (see `ClassUnderTest.baz` which instantiates a `SomeClass` object).

Consider the following test:

```
@Test
void testClassInstantiation() {
  final var spy = Mockito.spy(ClassUnderTest.class);
  spy.bar("name set on spy via bar");
  Assertions.assertEquals("name set on spy via bar", spy.getName());
  spy.baz("name set on spy via baz");
  Assertions.assertEquals("name set on spy via baz", spy.getName());
  spy.foo("name set on spy via foo");
  Assertions.assertEquals("name set on spy via foo", spy.getName());
}
```

The only difference is that the `Class<T>` overload of `Mockito.spy` is used instead of the object spy  method `T` of `Mockito.spy`. All assertions succeed in this case.

The same behavior can be observed with Mockito v3.3.3 and v4.7.0 (latest version of Mockito at the time of writing this question).

- Is this the expected behavior and if yes, what is the reason for this?
- Is there some documentation of this behavior?
- How can you avoid this behavior if a spy needs to be used (i.e. because of legacy tests) and no default constructor is available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is documented in the JavaDoc of [`Mockito#spy`](https://javadoc.org/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core/4.0.0/docs/org/mockito/Mockito.html#spy-T-):

> Mockito **does not** delegate calls to the passed real
> instance, instead it actually creates a copy of it. So if you keep
> the real instance and interact with it, don't expect the spied to be
> aware of those interaction and their effect on real instance state.
> The corollary is that when an **unstubbed** method is called **on the spy** but **not on the real instance**, you won't see any effects on the real instance.

And since all non-static classes automatically keep a reference to the containing instance (and that includes anonymous implementations), method calls will be dispatched to your original instance.

Crude ASCII diagram:

```
Spy -> original#impl -> original
```

Since the spy is a copy of the original, it has the same instance of the inner class. But this instance was created within the original, hence keeps a reference to the containing class (which is the original one).
The same would also be happening if you moved `new SomeClass` into the constructor or field initializer. It only works there, because the call is made after the copy has been created.

If you have a debugger, you can quickly verify by setting a breakpoint after your spy was created and then compare the object ids of the `impl` field. Or you make it accessible and assert:

```
class SpyVsSpy {
    @Test
    void testObjInstantiation() {
        final var toBeSpied = new ClassUnderTest();
        final var spy = Mockito.spy(toBeSpied);
        Assertions.assertSame(toBeSpied.impl, spy.impl);
        Assertions.assertNotSame(toBeSpied, spy);
    }
}

class ClassUnderTest {
    private String name = "initial value";

    public final SomeInterface impl = new SomeInterface() {
        @Override
        public void foo(String name) {
        }
    };

    private interface SomeInterface { void foo(String name);}
}
```

How to break `#bar`:

```
class ClassUnderTest {
  private SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass(); // keeps reference to "this"
  public void baz(String name) {
    someClass.foo(name);
  }
}
```

Comment: Great explanation, great answer! Appreciate it! I know the cited part of the documentation but since I did nothing with my original instance of `ClassUnderTest` (`toBeSpied`) I thought it is not relevant for my use-case. I also did the comparison of the object IDs for the inner instances before and saw that they were equal. I just totally forgot the (implicitly added) reference to the containing object.
This also explains why the tests using `Mockito.spy(ClassUnderTest.class);` work (since the “outer most” instance of `ClassUnderTest` is already a spy).